# What if condition should I use to handle an error which is trying to access a non-existent Key element in an array

Tags: php

I would like to give the user (as in programmer) an error upon trying to access a key element in an array which is non-existent. This code will make my explanation better. I believe that an *if condition* needs to be put here but I'm not sure what to input.

```
    function set(){
        $players = array('good' =>
                            array ('Angels', 'Guardians'),
                          'bad'=>
                            array('Devils', 'Imps'));

    return $players['bad'][1];
    //If I try to access Key element number 2 and above since all I have are elements 0(Devils) and 1(Imps) please show me an error.
    if (condition) {
      # code...
    }
```

}

```
  echo set();
```

Comment: I see now. It is a design choice then, really. You could throw an [`Exception`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php), you could handle it gracefully (for example, by falling back to `0` or `1`), you could return something that indicates an error, like `null`, ... just make sure to document how your method will behave, this will become the [method's contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract). Also try to be consistent in how you handle these things within your codebase.

Comment: I think you should provide the real code then. Right now, your method doesn't even take user input but is accessing the array with a hardcoded key that we know exists. Also, you should include *"the error"* you are getting within your question. Check out these guides: [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Use array_key_exists to check that a key exists before trying to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if (array_key_exists("somekey", $array))` to check whether the array contains that key (its value could still be null)

Use `if (isset($array["somekey"]))` to check whether the array contains a key and that keys value is not null.

In PHP 7+ you can also use a shorthand syntax:

```
$array["somekey"] = $array["somekey"]??null;
```

This will create the array key and set it to null if it does not exist. In an if:

```
if ($array["somekey"]??"banana" !== "banana") //does not exist  or has a value of banana. I like banans
```